# Ist das ein Wortspiel oder ein Wortwitz?

Tags: difference, terminology

Ich habe den Unterschied zwischen *Wortspiel* und *Wortwitz* nicht verstanden. Sind diese Beispiele Wortspiele oder Wortwitze? Was ist der Unterschied?

> Zwei Tomaten kreuzen eine Straße. Ein Auto überfährt eine Tomate. Die andere Tomate sagt: „Beeil dich, passierte Tomate!“
>
> Zwei Tomaten kreuzen eine Straße. Ein Auto überfährt eine Tomate. Welche ist die passierte Tomate?
>
> Du hast/hasst mich... gefragt.

Comment: Wobei der Witz mit den Tomaten im Englischen besser funktioniert. Im Deutschen müsste man nämlich eigentlich fragen "Welche Tomate hat die Straße passiert?", um die nicht überfahrene Tomate zu meinen.

Comment: @Swegi Ich habe es zuerst auch nicht verstanden, aber ich glaube, eine Tomate kam unter die Räder, und eine Tomate wurde vom Auto *passiert*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wikipedias Artikel für ["Wortwitz"](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wortwitz) ist ein Synonym und leitet weiter auf [Wortspiel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wortspiel).

Die [Definitionen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wortwitz) auf [Duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wortspiel) ähneln einander auch sehr:

> **Wortwitz** maskulin - auf Wortspielen, einem Wortspiel beruhender Witz
>
> **Wortspiel** -  Spiel mit Worten, dessen witziger Effekt besonders auf der Doppeldeutigkeit des gebrauchten Wortes oder auf der gleichen bzw. ähnlichen Lautung zweier aufeinander bezogener Wörter verschiedener Bedeutung beruht

Daraus würde ich folgern, daß kein bedeutender Unterschied zwischen den beiden Begriffen besteht.

Bezogen auf die Kategorisierung im Wikipedia-Artikel sind die ersten beiden Wortspiele in deinem Beispiel meinem Verständnis nach *Polysemien*, das dritte (das allerdings unvollständig ist bzw. in der vorliegenden Form noch nicht witzig :) ein *Buchstabendreher*.

Comment: Gerade das Rammstein-Beispiel: "Du hast/hasst mich... gefragt." finde ich nicht witzig, würde es aber dennoch als Wortspiel bezeichnen. Der Duden sagt zwar, ein Wortspiel hätte einen witzigen Effekt, aber vielleicht ist der kein Muss. Beim Wortwitz dagegen schon, da der Witz schon im Wort steckt.

Answer (score 7):

Bezogen auf den Witz sind es Synonyme.

Wortwitz kann aber auch die Fähigkeit des Sprechers beschreiben, sich in gewisser Weise auszudrücken.

> Er hat Wortwitz.

In diesem Wendung kann es nicht durch Wortspiel ersetzt werden.

Comment: Good point. ---